# Loading files via CDN vs compressing all CSS/JS to one file

Tags: javascript, css, performance, cdn, page-load-time

I have a specific question to my current needs:

I have a hosted server (their servers are located at my country + all users are from my country). This is not an Amazon AWS/Azure server where I can apply CDN services on my files.

Is it better to load CSS/JS files from **my** server, where I can compress all files to 1 .css and one .js file? Or is it still better to use an outsourced CDN for my libraries where my files aren't combined?

(gzip and caching is enabled on my server)

Comment: CDN is best. Suppose your website and Amazon uses jQuery CDN, then if the user has already visited amazon, your site wont have to load jquery from Internet.

Comment: The answers so far are referring to things like jquery. But are you talking about your own code only? edit: you answered this in comment below.

Comment: The OP and answers look like opinion-based. So I add my opinion. For very common files (`jquery`, `bootstrap`) use CDN. Less common resources could be bundled and served from a local server or served partially from CDN and partially from local server. In the case of low-traffic site (below 100 views per minute) it makes little difference. The difference may arise when you need to count each byte per request. In my opinion, the OP is an attempt of *premature optimization*.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using a CDN for common resources, such as say jQuery, is that if your visitor happens to have visited another site that is using the  same CDN resource (including the version), then this user will already have the resource cached. This helps build the appearance of a fast loading website.

But, it's a numbers game really, and your visitors will not see that benefit so much if it's an obsure resource.

Personally, I prefer to bundle my resources than to use a CDN, I can the create a shared vendor bundle across various pages, etc.

Comment: I use CDN for my jQuery actually. but that's the thing, for instance, I am using animate.css and wow.js, which might be rare to local users in my country (or at least for the users who are browsing my website), is it smarter to compress these files? although i have the CDN option?

Comment: I just looked up wow.js, it's only 3kb. My personal opinion is that the benefits would hardly be noticeable on such a small resource. But, if you can use the CDN and you don't think that will impact how you organise the code that uses that library, then definitely do, but otherwise for convenience to yourself, you can just bundle them (the conveniences might be local offline working for instance).

Answer (score 1):

For rare files and your own codez, do it yourself. Anyone returning to your site who has not cleared their browser will have the files, just as a CDN would have them.

Comment: I use CDN for my jQuery actually. but that's the thing, for instance, I am using `animate.css` and `wow.js` too, which might be rare to local users in my country (or at least for the users who are browsing my website), is it smarter to compress these files? although i have the CDN option?

Comment: Actually, i'm backtracking. Go with a cdn, except for your own stuff which you can combine and minimize. You could do tests if there's no cdn close to you to see which is faster, but at the very least, outsourcing the bandwidth for those files could be a bonus.